# how to sign up users without login in firebase/js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on administrator web site, and Actually I need to know how to sign up users without losing my admin sign up, Cause I need to make only admin can create users accounts. 
I'm using firebase Email/Pw authentification.

```
const CreateCh = document.querySelector('#CreateChaufeurs');

CreateCh.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

//get chaufeur info
const email = CreateCh['exampleEmail11'].value;
const password = CreateCh['examplePassword11'].value;
const Fname = CreateCh['Fname'].value;
const Address = CreateCh['exampleAddress'].value;
const Tel = CreateCh['exampleAddress2'].value;
const Ville = CreateCh['exampleCity'].value;
const Etat = CreateCh['exampleState'].value;
const Cp = CreateCh['exampleZip'].value;
const AGE = CreateCh['AGE'].value;
console.log(password, email, Fname,AGE,Address,Tel,Ville,Etat,Cp );
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });
});
```

but after the creation of the account, it automatically logs in with that new account.

Comment: What exactly u want?

Comment: I want to create accounts without changing the admin login. the problem is when the admin create a new account the session is converted to the new user account, I don't want that to happen, I want the admin just to make the new account with him stay i

Comment: Which session?.

Comment: I mean authenticator (went I try to create new user account automatically this account replace admin account and I need to stop that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a separate Firebase SDK instance to handle all of your account creation requests.

In it's simplest form, you can use:

```js
let authWorkerApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebase.app().options, 'auth-worker');
let authWorkerAuth = firebase.auth(authWorkerApp);
authWorkerAuth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE); // disables caching of account credentials

authWorkerAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
});
```

If you encounter errors such as *Firebase app 'auth-worker' is already initialised*, you can wrap it in a safe getter to avoid such an error:

```js
function getFirebaseApp(name, config) {
    let foundApp = firebase.apps.find(app => app.name === name);
    return foundApp ? foundApp : firebase.initializeApp(config || firebase.app().options, 'auth-worker');
}

let authWorkerApp = getFirebaseApp('auth-worker');
```

Comment: Nothing different when I insert auth-worker; https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ahkxpgtyss35or/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Loock at the Pic when I create new user admin changed to Not admin

Comment: You can't have used the code above correctly, as the console message before that says that the firebaseApp you are using is named `[DEFAULT]` and not `auth-worker`

Comment: @alabouhajja Can you link the first 10 or so lines of `auth.js`?

Comment: OK but also when I changed firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword to authWorkerAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword it still the some problem

Comment: Can you clear your cache and start from scratch. Log in as the admin and test again?

Comment: ok Thanks, Mr for helping